# Unity - Virtual tour in 3d model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, virtual-tour

I have a 3d model. It consists some streets.Actions are go straight, go back, left turn, right turn.

I attach a .cs file to camera. I use to go back&go staright below code :

```
v.z = this.gameObject.transform.position.z;
v.y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y;
v.x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;

if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.UpArrow ) )
    v.z += 0.5f;
else if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.DownArrow ) )
    v.z -= 0.5f;
```

It works for me. I attach a diffrent .cs file to the gameobject of 3d model. The file content is :

```
void Update() {
    if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.RightArrow ) )
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -0.1f*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));
    else if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.LeftArrow ) )
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, +0.1f*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));
}
```

But when I try to left&right turn, I am staying behind the buildings.

How can I turn right or left regularly in 3d model using model?

EDIT

My coordinate system and scene view is :

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "staying behind buildings"?

Comment: I try to turn right. When I use upper code, I am not on the street way., the buildings are front of me.

Comment: Could you remove Input.GetAxis(...) from your code and test again?

Comment: Some problem exists. Maybe should I set the model origin as my current position?

Comment: Also, why do you rotate around z - axis? Shouldn't you rotate it around Y axis?

Comment: I just edit my question. the coordinate system is there.

Comment: You either want to change the distance to the near clipping plane or do some clash detection to make sure that you don't move the camera through buildings. Have you plotted your camera path to see that it's where you think it is?

Comment: Ok so if your Y axis points up, you want to ratate around Y axis to turn left and right.

Comment: @ChrisF yes, I control it. The camera moves through buildings.

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka thank your help. I rotate Y axist but I can't create realistic tour. Turn right or left isn't easy this way for a user.

Comment: What do you mean by "realistic tour" can you axplain more in the question what do you want to achieve? Maybe some example?

Comment: Rotate and go staright is not easy. To be front of buildings, I have to many steps such as rotate, go back, rotate ...